# the Fourier transform of a constant

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, transformation

How to calculate the Fourier transform of a constant without the aid of duality property? In other words, how do I calculate
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-j\omega t}dt?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fourier transform of a constant is defined as 
$$
\mathcal{F}(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}ae^{-2\pi j \omega t}dt = a\delta(\omega)
$$
where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.

---

We can view the Dirac delta function as the limit of the Gaussian; that is,
$$
\lim_{\sigma\to 0}\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\Bigl(-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}\Bigr)
$$
Then we have
\begin{align}
\delta(t) &=
\lim_{\sigma\to 0}\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\Bigl(-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}\Bigr)\\ 
&=\lim_{\sigma\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\Bigl(-\frac{\omega^2\sigma^2}{2}\Bigr)e^{-i\omega t}d\omega\\ 
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-j\omega t}d\omega
\end{align}

Comment: My question is, how to calculate the integration?
It is easy to show that the Fourier transform of a constant is the Dirac delta function using duality property of FT, but I have no idea how to calculate the integration directly.